# iphone: how to stream audio from one iphone to another

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am looking to stream audio from an iphone, and let it play out of another iphone.  Are there any good libraries that will facilitate the process easily?  I am looking into Audio File Stream Services but I am not sure if it's the best way and can't find any examples

Answer (score 1):

This isn't available yet, but looks like what you're looking for.
http://audiob.us/

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not going to be easy and you are not going to find any libraries that will make it a simple task.

Basically, to connect to another device you need to use [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH1-SW1). Check out the [Peer to Peer Connectivity](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1) section. To learn about sessions b/w connected devices, you should reference the [Working With Sessions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/WorkingwithSessions/WorkingwithSessions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH101-SW1) section.